# What is the fastest way to simplify $\sqrt{a^2}$ for $a>0$

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

In my calculations I often end up with large expressions that contain a lot of terms like $\sqrt{a^2}$, where I know that $a>0$ is always satisfied.

I know that Mathematica won't simplify such expressions by default (which is good), since $a$ could be complex. I also know that one can use `Simplify` with `Assumptions` or `PowerExpand` to get rid of the square roots.

The issue is that my expressions can be potentially very large, so applying `Simplify` or `PowerExpand` in the intermediate steps is not really an option. It just costs too much time...

Consider for example

```
exp = Sum[coeff[i] Sqrt[ab^2], {i, 1, 20000}];
AbsoluteTiming[PowerExpand[exp];]
```

On my machine `PowerExpand` requires 7.7 seconds to get rid of the square roots, which is painfully slow.

Now I can use the dirty trick

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[Power[ab, 2], Rational[1, 2]] = ab;
Protect[Power];
```

and with

```
AbsoluteTiming[exp2 = exp;]
exp2[[1 ;; 10]]
```

the square roots are all gone in less than 0.05 seconds.

Of course, I know that it is almost always a bad idea to redefine system functions, but in this particular case I just cannot come up with any good alternative.

One possible solution is to do something like

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 sqrts = Cases[exp, Power[_, _Rational], Infinity] //DeleteDuplicates // Sort;
 sqrtsSimp = PowerExpand /@ sqrts;
 repRule = Thread[Rule[sqrts, sqrtsSimp]];
 exp2 = exp /. repRule;
]
```

This seems to be almost as fast as the dirty trick, but the disadvantage is that I have to explicitly apply it to my expressions (possibly after each subsequent evaluation). With redefined `Power`, however, the simplification is done automatically, so I know that I don't have to bother about square roots at all.

I wonder if there are better solutions to my problem? It may well be that I'm missing some obvious tricks to deal with such things.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to substitute it manually as

```
exp = Sum[coeff[i] Sqrt[ab^2], {i, 1, 20000}];
AbsoluteTiming[exp2 = exp /. Sqrt[ab^2] -> ab;]
```

> 0.028188, Null}

Answer (score 1):

A reasonably general approach is

```
exp /. Power[Power[a_, c_], d_] -> Power[a, c d]
```

Answer (score 0):

In a complicated expression, with many repeated subexpressions, it can be useful to extract the parts and simplifying before substituting back in

```
Union[Cases[exp, __Power, ∞]]
(* {b^2, Sqrt[a b^2]} *)

AbsoluteTiming[exp /. Thread[% -> PowerExpand[%]];]
(* {0.060599, Null} *)
```

Note that `Sqrt` is automatically changed to `Power` (despite appearances) so the rule must match that.